# Can't get different compilers to use specific header files?

Tags: c, linux, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a **C** project for college, and I want to use the `Sleep()` function in my header file. The people marking it could be using Linux and I'm developing in VS2013 for Windows. I found out that `Sleep()` exists in two different header files depending on whether the compiler uses Windows or Linux, I've looked over the web and found suggestions to use `"#ifdef"` in the preprocessor. However I'm new to preprocessor work so I'm not sure what to use when there's many different suggestions out there, I'm particularly unsure as to whether these suggestions are for the same purpose as mine, so apologies if this is a common question. I've tried the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
#include<windows.h>
#elif __linux
#include<unistd.h>
#else
#include<unistd.h>
#endif
```

This compiles fine in VS2013 but I get errors on a linux machine for `Sleep()` so the code I'm using doesn't seem to work outside of VS2013. Could someone explain what needs to be specified in order to get Windows and Linux to use their respective headers?

Comment: sleep() is defined but I don't think Sleep() is defined (on linux)..

Comment: Careful that the windows Sleep takes milliseconds as argument, while the unistd one takes seconds as argument.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux function is named `sleep()`, in lowercase, but the Windows one is `Sleep()`, with an uppercase S. And C is case-sensitive. Moreover, the Windows `Sleep()` takes the argument as milliseconds while the Linux alternative uses seconds.

So something like this is required:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
#include<windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep((x) * 1000)
#elif __linux
#include<unistd.h>
#else
#include<unistd.h>
#endif
```

Or if you prefer, you can do the other way around, but you'll have precision issues. (Consider using `nanosleep()` if that's an issue).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I said I don't use Linux so I wouldn't know about the formatting of the unistd.h version, but I'll test this out on a Linux system tomorrow and then answer this question.